# Cat biting other cat's neck

Tags: cats, behavior

Cat A will lick cat B while cat B is sleeping and then bite cat B's neck. It doesn't seem to hurt cat B, but why might cat A bite cat B?

Cat A is a male about full size and almost a year old.

Cat B is a male, a little bigger than the television remote and around 2 months old.

Answer (score 4):

When grooming themselves my cats sometimes seem to be biting their legs or tails. I think that's just to get rid of some hair or to help them lick the place.

My older cat was doing that to my kitten too.

So it is apparently normal behaviour if you say that cat B doesn't seem to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is scruffing behavior. It is partially play behavior and partially the biting cat showing / exerting dominance over the other cat.

Answer (score -3):

The "scruff" of the neck on a cat has no feeling, that's why all felines carry their young by the "scruff of the neck".

Research:  experience, I've owned a lot of cats.